# SQL considers search word as column in WHERE condition

Tags: sql

Let's say I have the following data table named `test_table`:

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A100 | B200 | C200 |
| 2 | A200 | A200 | C200 |
| 3 | A100 | B200 | C200 |
| 4 | A200 | A200 | C200 |

I would like to select all rows with a "A100" in col1. I tried the following but nothing worked:

`SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE col1=A100`

`SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE A100 IN col1`

`SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE col1 LIKE "A100"`

`SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE col1 LIKE "%A100%"`

I get the following error and I wonder why this happens:

> SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "A100" does not exist in test_table

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1):

You'll need simple quotes for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM test_table
WHERE col1 = 'A100'
```

Comment: Thanks -  its working.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE col1 = 'A100'
```

You received this error `SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "A100" does not exist in test_table` because of this query:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE A100 IN col1
```

because A100 is nor a column, it is the value. Your column is col1

Answer (score 0):

You need single quotes `'` for strings.

Double quotes `"` are used to delimit object names, for example if you have a column with spaces in the name `my column`, you would have to specify when the column name starts and ends:

```
SELECT "my column"
FROM some_table
```

The T-SQL/MSSQL equivalent is square brackets

```
SELECT [my column]
FROM some_table
```